# "Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive." when returning an `Import`ed image for `VertexShapeFunction`

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to use `Graph` (not `GraphPlot`) and replace some of the vertices with an image, like so:

```
Graph[
 graph,
 EdgeWeight -> edges,
 EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight",
 VertexLabels -> "Name",
 VertexShapeFunction -> {_?(KeyExistsQ[sprites, #] &) -> 
    SpriteVertexFunction}
 ]
```

I define `SpriteVertexFunctions` without really using any of the callback parameters:

```
SpriteVertexFunction[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := sprites[name];
```

And `sprites` is an `Association` of numbers to imported images, which I've tried `Rasterize`ing too:

[image]

The error I'm getting is

> Graphics is not a Graphics primitive or directive.

Can `Graph` not draw verticies with arbitrary images? Do I have to use `GraphPlot` instead?

Comment: Use `Inset[]` with `VertexShapeFunction`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Property`, e.g.

```
sims = MapIndexed[Property[#2[[1]], VertexShape -> #1] &, simpsons]
g = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 6, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6};
Graph[sims, g, VertexSize -> 0.6]
```

I am posting image of code to see effect:

[image]

Comment: D'oh! (+1)$\phantom{}$